# Excel files downloaded from a GitHub repository become corrupt

Tags: excel, github

[This discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/217) says that Excel files downloaded from a repository become corrupt because of the way the HTTP GET request is built.

But let's say I just need a button for dowloading a .xlsx file from there which is not corrupted. Is it possible somehow, without talking about HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH to download in any case if you really don't want to use HTTP.

[downloading file using SFTP with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433315/downloading-file-using-sftp-with-vba)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).