# Access excel info located in sftp

Tags: excel, vba, ftp, sftp

I'm automating a process, where I need to get the info in an excel file located in an sftp.
Is there any way to refresh that info into an excel where I save the historical info?

Nowadays, I'm recibing an email with the excel and the info, but I need to automatize this process, so I don't need to open the email, download the excel, open the excel and copy and paste the info from the first excel into my excel with the historical info.

Comment: You can download a file from sftp edit it and upload it again. You cannot edit a file in a sftp location directly. Have a look at [SFTP upload with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754928/sftp-upload-with-vba). Give it a try on your own and if you get stuck or errors come back with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the file and them link to the file downloaded.

But i think the best way for you is learn about SHAREPOINT , 
its a microsoft tool who can share excel online and them u can access real time from anywhere, Hope you enjoy it.