# Automating Macros for an excel file in SFTP location

Tags: excel, vba, sftp, winscp

I have an excel file in an SFTP location with inbuilt macros in it. I want to do an automation such that the macro runs at a certain time daily in the SFTP server.
Initially I did it using task scheduler, but now that the file is not available locally and since it is residing in the SFTP Location I am unsure on what to do.
Help.

Comment: Cannot you use task scheduler on the remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The SFTP server is a file store, not an application server.

So, download the file in question to a local folder, run your macro using this local file, and - when done - upload it to the SFTP server overwriting the old file.

Comment: Correct, if the SFTP is the only interface to the server you have. But you often might have an SSH shell access in addition to SFTP. With the shell access, it might be doable.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Could I add a time function in the macro to run it automatically at a specific time and then schedule an automation task to open the file in the SFTP at that specific time ? Since macro time schedule doesn't work unless the file is open, would this be a good approach?

Comment: Check this out: [SFTP upload with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754928/sftp-upload-with-vba).

Comment: Again, as this answers says, this is not doable if your have only the SFTP access. If you have other services available on the server, you have to tell us (and probably ask a new question for that).

Comment: I will check that, yeah. I'm pretty new to this concept and hence the doubts. Thank you for your insights. Really appreciate it.